# Изменить выделение запроса в PL\SQL Developer

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql-developer

Настраиваю цвета в PL\SQL Developer. При запуске запрос выделяется цветом(см картинку). Не могу найти настройку, которая за это отвечает. Сейчас текст запроса после запуска тяжело читать. Как и где изменить цвет выделения запроса?

[image: часть экрана]

Comment: Можно уточнить вы выделяете запрос перед тем как выполнить, чтоб указать какой именно исполнять, так? а черный фон и зеленый код это вы настроили?

Comment: Включена галочка автоселект. Выполняется запрос, на котором стоит курсор. Цвета сам настаивал, не нашёл готовых цветовых схем

Comment: попробуйте в [программное окно] [горячее выделение]

Comment: @4per я ошибся. Вы были правы, это то что надо. Оформите ответом, приму как верное. Мой мозг подвел меня, и я перевел не правильно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как выяснилось, за желаемую настройку цвета отвечает цветной прямоугольник, при нажатии на который открывается меню выбора цвета.

[image]

Данный прямоугольник можно найти в ГУИ программы:

- в русифицированной версии <kbd>Главное меню</kbd>→<kbd>Инструменты</kbd>→<kbd>Предпочтения</kbd>→<kbd>Типы окон</kbd>→<kbd>Программное окно</kbd>→<kbd>Горячее выделение</kbd>
- в оригинале <kbd>Главное меню</kbd>→<kbd>Tools</kbd>→<kbd>Preferences</kbd>→<kbd>Window Types</kbd>→<kbd>Program Window</kbd>→<kbd>*Третий цветной прямоугольник сверху вниз (не знаю, что там в оригинале написано)*</kbd>